# Botão criado Dinamicamente não dispara a asp-action - core 2 MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, mvc

Eu tenho uma cshtml (view) neste pagina eu uso um modelo tipado e dentro uso um formulario POST, eu crio uma div(dinamicamnete com ajax) com alguns componentes, TODOS aparecem normal, mas o botão de disparar uma action no controller não funciona, se eu deixar statico o mesmo dispara e chama a action.
C# .net Core 2.1 com MVC e Bootstrap

```
class ReimpressaoView {

constructor(elemento) {

    this._elemento = elemento;
}
_template(model) {
    return ` <button asp-action="ConfirmaReimpressaoCertificadoPDF" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Imprimir
                     </button>
             <div class="jumbotron">
               <div class="container">
                  <p class="text-justify" style="font-size:medium">O R.G. Pesquisado é Referente ao certificado emitido em <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="float:center"> ${model.dataEmissaoAntecedentes} </span></p>
                  <p class="text-justify" style="font-size:medium">Com o código <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="float:center">${model.codigoUnico}</span></p>
               <hr />
                  <p class="lead" style="font-size:medium"><strong>Obs:</strong>Este certificado tem validade até a data de <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="float:center"> ${model._dataEmissaoAntecedentes}</span></p>
              </div>  
        `;
}

update(model) {
    this._elemento.innerHTML = this._template(model);
}
```

AJAX

```
enviarRgUsuarioCertificado(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
             if (this._inputrgReimpressao.value === "") {
            alert('Favor preencher o campo RG!!');
            return;        }
     let model = { RG: this._inputrgReimpressao.value }
        $.ajax({
            url: '/certificado/GetusuarioAntecedentesRG',
            type: 'Post',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                 dataemissao = response.dataEmissaoAntecedentes;
                 codigoUnico = response.codigoUnico;             
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: apresente o código

Comment: Obrigado, sou novo no stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não vai funcionar porque você está escrevendo um componente do Razor, que deveria ser interpretado do lado do servidor antes de renderizar a view, em seu html já pronto e na tela do usuário.

```
<button asp-action="ConfirmaReimpressaoCertificadoPDF" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  Imprimir
</button>
```

Você precisa escrever o elemento já renderizado, se pretende adicioná-lo dinamicamente via javascript.

O que seria algo como:

```
<button type="submit" formaction="/SuaController/ConfirmaReimpressaoCertificadoPDF" class="btn btn-primary" >
   Imprimir
</button>
```

Comment: Muitíssimo Obrigado! Funcionou Perfeitamente!

Comment: @ThiagoBarros  Se a proposta é a resposta para a sua pergunta, é importante votar como útil e aceitar como resposta, assim a sua pergunta e a solução podem ser úteis para outros usuários que venham a enfrentar o mesmo problema